# vuejs default properties set from vue-i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I would like to set a default property from dictionary like this:

```
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: this.$t("basic.confirm"),
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    }
  }, ...
```

The `$t` is a [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n), and I would like to set my title from dictionary, if its not defined in the parent class. But I got error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$t is not a function

Similar error If I reload without `this`.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $t is not defined

But If I log out this value in the mount method it works well.

Is there a solution of setting default property from the dictionary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you do the same in compositio api

Answer (score 42):

One solution is to have the key or part of it as default props like

```
title: {
   type: String,
   default: "basic.confirm", //or "confirm"
 },
```

and in template:

```
<h1>{{ $t(title) }}</h1> //or $t("basic." + title)
```

edit: you can access $t inside function

```
title: {
  type: String,
  default: function () {
    return this.$t("basic.confirm")
  }
},
```

Comment: its not a bad idea!

Comment: note that arrow syntax doesn't work: `default: () => { this.$t("basic.confirm") }`, but function syntax above does.

Comment: @LaurelT your arrow function is not returning the value `default: () => this.$t("basic.confirm")`

Comment: Keep in mind the context of this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60547546/10598904

Comment: How does this work in Vue3?

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to have the key or part of it as default props like

```
 title: {
   type: String,
   default: "", 
 },
```

and in template:

```
    <h1>{{ $t(titlep) }}</h1>
```

and in script:

```
    import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
    ...
    setup(props) {
      const { t }  = useI18n()
      const titlep = computed(() =>
        props.title ? props.title : t('basic.confirm')
      )
      return { titlep }
    }
```